# Export firewall rules applied from GPO using powerhsell

Tags: powershell

I am using the code below to export locally applied firewall rules to a .csv.

```
$Rules=(New-object –comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules
$Rules | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This script does not export fw rules applied through GPO. How do I get the GPO applied rules to export aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Win8/Server2012 and newer:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore RSOP
```

On older systems, you could parse a `gpresult` or RSOP xml. For example, for inbound rules:

```
$xmlpath = "C:\example.xml"
& gpresult.exe /x C:\example.xml
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlpath)
($xml.DocumentElement.ComputerResults.ExtensionData.extension | 
    ? {$_.type -like "*firewall*"}).inboundfirewallrules | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The term 'Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ? I am using powershell v2

Comment: Then use `gpresult.exe /x C:\example.xml`

Comment: Could you please modify the script? its either not working or i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Answer edited to use `gpresult` rather than the cmdlet

Comment: Yup, worked this time. However, it does not export like the script i've been using above. Anyway to do that?

Comment: Pipe it into `Export-CSV` just like you did in your script. ` | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation` Also if an answer works for you, it's best practice to accept it.

Comment: Are you able to edit it one last time? I exported it to .csv but still showing in XML format. your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134501/discussion-between-benh-and-nebelz-cheez).

Comment: Hello BenH, please see the chat.